NiceMatrix: no shape found
I am going sightly nuts trying to draw some lines on a nicematrix. As far as I can see, I am following the instructions in the manual, but the code below does not compile giving the error

Package pgf Error: No shape named `3-3' is known.

I have tried placing \NotEmpty into this cell, together with more exotic hacks like \phantom{1}, but nothing I try works.
Does anyone have a suggestion for fixing the following code?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\[
    \begin{bNiceMatrix}[
            first-row,
            code-for-first-row=\scriptstyle\rotate\color{blue},
            last-col,
            code-for-last-col=\scriptstyle\color{red},
     ]
             &                     & \text{column $j$} &        & \\
      0      & \Cdots\hspace*{4mm} &\Cdots             & 0      & \\[6mm]
      \Vdots &                     & 1                 & \Vdots & \text{row $i$}\\[10mm]
      0      & \Cdots              & \Cdots   & 0      & \\
      \CodeAfter
        \tikz\draw[blue](0-3.south)--(3-1); % works
        \tikz\draw[blue](0-3.south)--(3-3); % fails
    \end{bNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}

This is supposed to be a matrix with a vertical line appearing down column j. Instead, I get the following, where the line pointing south-east from (0,3) is the result of the node (3-3) not being recognised.

The line from (0,3) to (3,1) is there only as an example of what should happen. Ideally, I would like to put these lines into a \CodeBefore[create-cell-nodes]...\Body block, but as I cannot get the \CodeAfter block to work I am being less ambitious.
I could easily achieve what I want using a TikZ matrix of nodes, but my real aim is to showcase nicematrix...
I am using nicematrix 2024/02/19 v6.27a, which is the version that ships with TeXLive 2024.

I agree that the behavior of \NotEmpty in conjunction with \Cdots is odd. I will take a look at that.
However, in your case, I would not use the ``cell-nodes'' of the form i-j but the nodes of the form i-|j which are at the intersection of the (virtual) rules of the tabular. In that syntax, it's possible to use a decimal point and a digit after i and j in order to adjust the position (eg: i.4-|j.3).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\[
    \begin{bNiceMatrix}[
            first-row,
            code-for-first-row=\scriptstyle\rotate\color{blue},
            last-col,
            code-for-last-col=\scriptstyle\color{red},
     ]
    \CodeBefore
        \tikz \draw [red] (3.7-|1) -- (3.7-|last) ; 
        \tikz \draw [blue] (1-|3.5) -- (last-|3.5) ; 
    \Body
             &                     & \text{column $j$} &        & \\
      0      & \Cdots\hspace*{4mm} &\Cdots             & 0      & \\
      \\
      \Vdots &                     & 1                 & \Vdots & \text{row $i$}\\
      \\
      0      & \Cdots              & \Cdots   & 0      & \\
    \end{bNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}



OK, here is a hack that does what I want:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\[
    \begin{bNiceMatrix}[
            first-row,
            code-for-first-row=\scriptstyle\rotate\color{blue},
            last-col,
            code-for-last-col=\scriptstyle\color{red},
     ]
     \CodeBefore[create-cell-nodes]
        \tikz\draw[blue](0-3.south)--++(0,-1.5);
        \tikz\draw[red](2-5.west)--++(-2.5,0);
     \Body
             &                     & \text{column $j$} &        & \\
      0      & \Cdots &\Cdots      & 0                 & \\%[6mm]
      \Vdots &                     & 1                 & \Vdots & \text{row $i$}\\%[10mm]
      0      & \Cdots              & \NotEmpty\Cdots   & 0      & \\
    \end{bNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}

which produces

Note the slightly unusual node names for the first-row and last-col cells.
Assuming that I am not misusing the package, I suspect that the problem is that the (3,3)-cell only contains a \Cdots command, which isn't really in the cell, and that the \NotEmpty command is unable to correct for this.

You are right: a cell with only a command like \Cdots is considered as "empty" by nicematrix and nicematrix does not create node in the empty cells (by design : in order to speed up compilation). The concept of "empty cell" is used by nicematrix when it draws the continuous dotted lines and for the so-called empty corners.

@F.Pantigny Thanks for your really nice package. Even though a cell contains \Cdots is empty, adding \NotEmpty probably should rectify this, but it doesn't seem to.
